# Assign the cluster number for each observation for time series data with hclust in R

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, hierarchical-clustering

I have a time series data with 4 variables over about 5 years. I would like to cluster the data using `hclust` method in R. I would like to cluster the observations. My code works. However, I would like to identify the specific cluster for each observation. That is, I would like to add the number of the cluster beside each observation. My code gave me an error. I understand the error. So is there any way can I achieve my point.

Here is my try:

```
library(TSclust)
library(cluster)    # clustering algorithms
library(tseries)
library(zoo)
library(dtw)
library(dtwclust)
library(dplyr)
##Load the data
data("EuStockMarkets")
##Save the data
dat <- EuStockMarkets

res <- lapply(split(as.zoo(EuStockMarkets), as.integer(time(EuStockMarkets))), as.ts)
## Re-define the data
datNew <- ts(rbind(res$`1995`,res$`1996`,res$`1997`, res$`1998`))
d <- dist(datNew, method = "DTW")
hc1 <- hclust(d, method = "average" )
sub_grp <- cutree(hc1, k = 4)
table(sub_grp)
datNew%>%
  mutate(cluster = sub_grp) %>%
  head
```

It returns me an error:

```
 Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
 no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "c('mts', 'ts', 'matrix')"

In addition: Warning message:
`mutate_()` is deprecated as of dplyr 0.7.0.
Please use `mutate()` instead.
See vignette('programming') for more help
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the problem is that your `datNew` is not a `data.frame`. Looking at:

```
class(datNew)
[1] "mts"    "ts"     "matrix"
```

And this gives to you your error. If you put it as a `data.frame`:

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(timeseries=as.matrix(datNew), date=time(datNew))%>%
           # use mutate() instead of mutate_()
           mutate(cluster = sub_grp) %>%
           head()
```

It should work, hoping it's the result you need.

```
  timeseries.DAX timeseries.SMI timeseries.CAC timeseries.FTSE date cluster
1        2110.77         2673.5         1956.0          3083.4    1       1
2        2097.34         2656.2         1927.8          3095.8    2       1
3        2074.68         2628.8         1894.2          3065.6    3       1
4        2097.51         2628.8         1881.2          3065.5    4       1
5        2079.19         2628.8         1881.2          3065.5    5       1
6        2068.92         2612.3         1885.9          3065.7    6       1
```

**EDIT**

In case is needed you can try this using hclust on after log and dif:

```
res <- lapply(split(as.zoo(EuStockMarkets), as.integer(time(EuStockMarkets))), as.ts)
datNew <- ts(rbind(res$`1995`,res$`1996`,res$`1997`, res$`1998`))

dat.log <- log(datNew)
dat.diff <- diff(dat.log)
Logreturns <- dat.diff

# using a different dist, due an error, the idea is the same
d <- dist(Logreturns)

hc1 <- hclust(d, method = "average" )
sub_grp <- cutree(hc1, k = 4)


data.frame(timeseries=as.matrix(Logreturns), date=time(Logreturns))%>%
  mutate(cluster = sub_grp) %>% 
  head()
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works. However, I accidentally not add my log data, which cause me an error. `Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `cluster`.
x Input `cluster` can't be recycled to size 948.
i Input `cluster` is `sub_grp`.
i Input `cluster` must be size 948 or 1, not 949`

Comment: If you would like to help me with it. It will be a very appreciated help.

Comment: Thank you so much. I do not know how to thank you. I have edited my question and added the new data.

Comment: I did the log before the sub_grp.

Comment: Oh I see, the problem is that you've applied diff, that removes one row (in this case), then you want to "paste" the sub_grp to it. It's not going to work, because one is 948 length, the other 949 (this is the error). The real question is: is it correct what you're doing, attaching clusters to the differencies instead of the values? I do not see a clever method to choose how to cut the clustering vector. You're attaching the cluster vector to the differencies, not the values, but you've calculated it on the values.

Comment: Maybe you can cluster the differencies, if it make sense: the numbers of rows etc are going to match, but I do not know if in your analysis has sense.

Comment: Probably yes, but I was saying that if you first apply log and diff, then the procedure of clustering, the numbers of rows of the data frame and the clustering vector is going to match. The question (that I cannot answer, because it's about your analysis and it's not about programming) is if this make sense to your analysis. I suppose yes, due you're transforming your time series (for some reason) but keep in mind it's the log dif.

Comment: Ok. I see your point. You are correct. I think I should cluster before taking the log and the differences.